# Best communication channel to tell user that they get banned/suspended/terminate

Tags: mobile, messages, user-communication

Which product communication do you think is the best to convey:

- User get temporary suspension, and therefore they couldn't login
- User get suspension and need to appeal
- User get unsuspend, the appeal is granted
- Partner get terminate because violating the terms

So far I could only think of these channels : Email, SMS/Whatsapp, push notification, do you have anymore suggestion channels?

Will it appropriate to tell suspension or unsuspend through push-notification? Or to terminate partner using email?

Comment: This is something you really need to test. There are just too many variable for us to provide and strong answer for your particular case

Comment: Agreed, but how to test it? Because it's a sensitive issue, I'm hesitate to do a user interview since the target will be user who get suspended/blocked, and I'm afraid they will be too angry to answer.

Comment: Run task based testing using a prototype with target user types. Present them with one of your scenarios at random and ask them what they understand from it and how they feel about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't make a comment on other posts due to less than 50 reputation, so I'll put my thoughts here.

Regarding the testing comment from Andrew Martin, you could use it as a hypothetical scenario to see how the user judges the question and see what response is given. I do agree that it is a negative scenario though and that this could provoke a negative response from the user, and potentially make them less willing to provide information. You could end the user interview with this question to not tamper with other results.

In terms of communication, it would be determined by the user's communication preferences they setup when creating an account. It also would be decided by your companies policy on communicating changes to a user's account. I know PayPal e-mail you any changes to your account, whether it is a suspension, permanent bans or even privacy changes. The e-mail method will allow more information to be provided and give the user links to be able to appeal bans or check the status of their appeals and it is more professional. SMS/Whatsapp comes across as too personal for a negative impact to the user. You could prompt the user via SMS/Whatsapp to check their email, but it would depend on how you message this across.

Hope this helps. Keep us updated as I'd like to know the outcome :)

Answer (score 0):

The single best way would be on login / access of the application or service.

If you have methods to send communication such as a preferred contact method (email, text etc.) that's a good place to send a message, but it will often be missed and should not be the only place the information is sent.

Comment: Do you think that texting user that we suspend them because xx reason will be appropriate? Or is it better to email them?

Comment: @Alexa Ideally your user has selected previously how they like to be contacted.If their preferred method of contact is text, then it is absolutely appropriate